# As a non-admin user on Windows 10, how do I simulate a timeout when visiting a certain domain?

Tags: windows-10, hosts, timeout

I'm using Windows 10, but as a user without administrative privileges.  I would like to simulate a timeout when any network call is made to myexample.com.  Normally, I could create an entry in the "hosts" file that routes traffic for the domain to 127.0.0.1, or something similar, but without access to the "hosts" file, I'm curious what the best way is to simulate this behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100841/artificially-create-a-connection-timeout-error

Comment: @spikey_richie, I guess I'm not seeing how any of those answers could be used to break an app that is calling `myexample.com` without modifying the program, unless you can subvert DNS or use hosts. I guess one option would be to configure an upstream firewall to block that traffic with a drop (not reject), but that does rely on the user being able to perform or request a firewall change.

Comment: Unplug Ethernet and/or shut WiFi? If you need to do this repeatedly, there are inexpensive Ethernet switches.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I was thinking the same initially, but it occurs to me that if the interface goes into an offline state, then at best the app will notice and react to the state change, and in the worst, the app will crash because the interface its ports are on just disappeared, so it may not test an actual timeout error. you may be on to something with the switch though, because if you put the switch in-line and unplug its upstream to the from switch to network, that would leave the interface active. but it also may kick a name resolution or connection error other than a timeout error.

Comment: @op, what precisely are you attempting to accomplish? do you really need a TCP timeout (as opposed to another error like name resolution, broken streams to the port, inability to create port, destination unreachable, etc)? are you able to reconfigure the application to use another target? can you get an admin to configure DNS or firewall?

Comment: If you can administrate your router, and you can manage DNS entries in it, or you can setup a DNS server somewhere that you can administrate, you can use that as a replacement for the hosts file. Just set its DNS server of what your current DNS server is, and change your own DNS server to that DNS server. You possibly have to do this from the router or DHCP server. One option could be pi-hole.